# Sandbox access to iTunes library on OSX

Tags: macos, itunes, sandbox

I am using the entitlement com.apple.security.assets.music.read-only to get access to the users iTunes music location.... BUT.... how do I (while sandboxed) actually read where that location is?

Some users with my app non-sandboxed have iTunes libraries and data files outside ~/Music folder :-/

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? Meta data for songs in the library, playing music or actually reading the songs/music files?

Comment: I am trying to access the iTunes xml file and then the library files... I need to know the library path itself as some users have multiple iTunes libraries. Id like to populate the default library